# Can you add a custom message to the IFileOperation warning message for a folder?

Tags: winapi, windows-shell

I use `IFileOperation` to delete files and folders.   The folders just says it's going to delete it but doesn't warn that all contents will be deleted as well (I understand it may not want to count them if a lot of items, but be nice if had an option).    I'd like to add that warning.  Is there a way?  If not, Could I have my own prompt but still have it show its progress?

TIA!!

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the problem you are trying to solve. It's hard for me to imagine how deleting a folder could not have the effect of deleting all of its content.

Comment: Do you want to show two warnings? You can hook delete events https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperationprogresssink-predeleteitem also do you already use FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-setoperationflags#fof_wantnukewarning-0x4000

Comment: @SimonMourier yes, that looks interesting.  I'd really like the single prompt with just more warning that all contents will be deleted as well.  But this IFileOperationProgressSink looks like it may be a decent way to go (maybe even have it auto answer and catch that hook).  How do I use IFileOperationProgressSink?  Do I query for it on the `IFileOperation` before the `PerformOperation()` ?   I don't use that flag since I presume default (no suppression), although shift-del didn't seem to to change anything, always recycle bin.

Comment: You can use it two ways. First you have to build a COM object that implements IFileOperationProgressSink, and then pass it to `fo->Advise(yourSink)` or/and use it for each operation `fo->DeleteItem(item, yourSink)`.